# Android thread repeating without clicking button

Tags: android, multithreading

hi am new to programming. am starting a thread by using onClick(View v).it works fine. now i want to repeat the "button click" by without clicking the button again. Am searching for about 5 hours. but i didn't get any answer. i user button.performClick(); but nothing happened. i want to restart my thread.

**Receiver:**

```
private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!connected) {
            serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
            if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                cThread.start();
                connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);

                connectPhones.setPressed(false);
                connectPhones.invalidate();
                Handler handler1 = new Handler();
                Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {


                        connectPhones.performClick();
                        connectPhones.setPressed(true); 
                        connectPhones.invalidate(); 
                        connectPhones.setPressed(false); 
                        connectPhones.invalidate(); 

                    }
                };
                handler1.postDelayed(r1, 1000);

            }  
        }
    }
};

public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, ServerActivity.SERVERPORT);
            connected = true;

            final String path = "/sdcard/all.png";
            File file = new File(path);


            ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            int nRead = 0;
            byte[] data = new byte[socket.getReceiveBufferSize()];
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream( path );
          //  while(connected == true){
                while( (nRead = reader.read(data)) != -1 ){
                    fileOutputStream.write( data, 0, nRead );
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                    data = new byte[socket.getReceiveBufferSize()];
                }
                fileOutputStream.close();
            //}


                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        image.postInvalidate();
                    }
                });

                file.delete();

            reader.close();

         //connectPhones.performClick();
           /* while (connected) {
                try {
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                .getOutputStream())), true);
                        // WHERE YOU ISSUE THE COMMANDS
                        out.println("Hey Server!");
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                }
            }*/
            socket.close();
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);

        }
        connected = false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: post relevant snippet of code

Comment: How can you click a button without actually clicking it? Be clear.

Comment: you can use a handler to repeat the actions performed inside the button click

Comment: When do you want to restart the thread?

Comment: @naddy after clicking the button for first time, it should be clicked again programmatically with delay of few seconds. is it possible?

Comment: @naddy after receiving the first file i want to restart the receiver thread to receive second file.

Comment: @tsp i tried that with ui thread but nothing happened.

Comment: Where you are making connected flag as false. Can you check whether it is not coming in if part or in onclick it may be coming to onclick but not going inside of if.

Comment: @bharat sharma i declared private boolean connected = false; in the main class

Comment: @nick you declared connected = false in main. Now when you click on button you are creating thread and making connected = true which is in try catch block. but you are making it false in catch block which will only execute when error fires. So if download successful then where you are making connected = false. You should make connected = false in finally.

Comment: once you write connected = false after catch block (not inside catch) and then check!

Comment: @bharat i used it below the catch block. but nothing happened.where i want to use it exactly?

Comment: you tell me first when you are calling  button.performClick() on click called or not.

Comment: i referred the below answer i used it on onclick(). but it works for few seconds. after that i need to click the button again.

Comment: that is a message handler only one time it will work after button click I think.

Comment: is any other way for clicking the button?

Comment: I modified your code you test and tell and remove handler from your button click code and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your purpose I have created one example code. This code is working perfectly. You can try this. You can write your code below to //DOWNLOAD FILE HERE comment.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    boolean connected = false;
    Button button_example = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         
        button_example = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button_example.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "button clicked called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("bb message called");
                if (!connected) {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            connected = true;
                            // DOWNLOAD FILE HERE.
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    connected = false;
                                    button_example.performClick();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    thread.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: after downloading first file it is crashing.

Comment: Its a different problem or above problem. What it is showing in stack trace?

Comment: i removed my handler but i didn't use UI Thread for performClick(). now its working fine. thanks Bharat Sharma

Comment: i am also feeling good now. i have one doubt. we you are using thread.sleep(1000) below the downloading process?

Comment: @nick I was testing it so I forgot to remove. you should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `onClick` method:

```
 btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButton);

            btn.setPressed(false);
            btn.invalidate();
            Handler handler1 = new Handler();
            Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {


                 btn.performClick();
                 btn.setPressed(true); 
                 btn.invalidate(); 
                 btn.setPressed(false); 
                 btn.invalidate(); 

                }
            };
            handler1.postDelayed(r1, 1000);
```

Comment: i works for few clicks only. after that it did not works. then i have to click the button again.